npm start error with .NET core and angular as single pages
I've been trying for a while to create a project in .NET Core and use Angular for the frontend, using single pages. After creating the project by following Microsoft's guide to the letter and running it with HTTPS, it shows me the following errors:
cli error
I'm using windows 11.
And on visual studio i have this message:
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (82028) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager: Error: Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'.
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (77016) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (76840) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (79908) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (64088) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (80724) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[68072] 3dPrintProject.Server.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

Can someone help me understand how to solve the problem? I'll be grateful for it for life.
I've tried searching online for a solution, checking if there were any version incompatibilities, but nothing worked. I expect to run and build the project correctly.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Try to run npm install --save-dev run-script-os command in your angular project and try again.
